# Android get Certificates added by User under User Crenentials

Tags: android, certificate

I have .pkcs12 certificate and after installing it on android (11/12) device it is listing under settings->security->User credentials

I'm using the below code to show all certificates but I could see only the system Trusted Certificates.

```
val result = ArrayList<Pair<String, KeyStore>>()
val ks: KeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidCAStore")
ks.load(null, null)
val aliases = ks.aliases()
while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
    val alias = aliases.nextElement() as String
    val cert = ks.getCertificate(alias) as X509Certificate
    result.add(Pair(alias, ks))
    Log.i("TAG", alias)
    Log.i("TAG", cert.toString())
}
```

I also used the following network-security-config.

```
<network-security-config xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false">
    <trust-anchors>
        <certificates src="user"
            tools:ignore="AcceptsUserCertificates" />
        <certificates src="system"/>
    </trust-anchors>
</base-config>
```

Any idea on how to get the certificates installed under the User Credentials?